# Not able to iterate a dbset

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am just beginning to learn c#, mvc/.net framework so excuse my noob question.

I get an "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" when calling the SendMailToAllSubscribers method in the following code:

```
public class ProductDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ShoppingCart> Shoppingcarts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Subscriber> Subscribers { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfSubscribers()
    {
        return Subscribers.Count();
    }

    public void SendMailToAllSubscribers()
    {
        foreach (var subscriber in Subscribers.ToList())
        {
            var test = 1;
        }
    }
```

Am i not allowed to loop the dbset this way?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, resolved the problem in another part of the application.